# how to get the value from json object that have a similar id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

im sending a ajax call that return a json like this

```
{"2":"/orangehrm/symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewPhoto/empNumber/1","3":"/orangehrm/symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewPhoto/empNumber/2","1":"/orangehrm/symfony/web/webres_552df88c832965.06437943/orangehrmMessengerPlugin/image/default-photo.png"}
```

the calling function have argument passed this is a integer

i want to get the value that correspond to given id for example 2 how to do this
is the way im using correct

```
function getUrl(sid){
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: shortUrl + 'messenger/getImgUrls',
            data: {suids: [sid]},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            cache: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                conversationId = msg.sid;

            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });}
 }
```

Comment: Wait what are you wanting to do (with out code) explain i got the picture your making an AJAX request to get the paths of images at the given SID's? if thats the case with sid not already an array before the `$.ajax`

Comment: this is just a mock situation please understand the ajax is returning a object with several objects as stated before .my problem is how to refer to them with the sid

Comment: you can simply use it by `jsonObject["2"]` I couldn't understand, what's the issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

have to use

```
conversationId = msg[sid];
```